# Angular/animate Bootstrap elements (input groups)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YbkMTpAW4opjMrNTG23T?p=preview) is here

Definitely not a CSS transition/guru, but I'm trying to make clicking on an icon slide in the input.  I have this working, but as soon as the animation is finished my icon blows up to the width of the containing div and I'm not sure why.

Markup

```
  <form class="form">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-5">
      <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" ng-click="hideInput = !hideInput">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control animate-hide" ng-hide="hideInput" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Styles

```
.animate-hide {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.75s;
  -o-transition: all linear 0.75s;
  transition: all linear 0.75s;
}
.animate-hide.ng-hide {
  width: 0;
}
.glyphicon-flag {
  color: #d9534f !important;
}
```

Everything besides the button expanding when the animation complets works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the CSS `display` property of the `input-group-addon` is set to `table-cell` by Bootstrap. When your animation is finished, the input is hidden which makes the flag icon expand to take all remaining space. You can fix this in various ways, one simple option is to add an empty `span` after the input. For example:

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="input-group col-sm-5">
    <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" ng-click="hideInput = !hideInput">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
    </span>
    <input class="form-control animate-hide" ng-hide="hideInput" />
    <span></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Example plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qPvbXtEUzvWfsZPkmVRq?p=preview

Comment: You beat me to it :) One thing that I would change though is instead of using a <span> is to use a <div> instead. This way you have a block level element that you can set the height property on to match the height of the Bootstrap input. Here is my implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/qzLJExPQ2EQ3sYqs7wdR?p=preview

Comment: @JoshTaylor That's a good call, I just threw any old element in the to demonstrate the issue & solution.

Comment: @DavidG @JoshTaylor Great recommendations both of you, I appreciate it.  I incorporated both techniques and added `padding:6px 0;` to prevent the input from "snapping" shut at the end of the animation.  Final Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XbNc3eNLHm7p0RJtzJu9?p=preview